# Resource_Semaphore

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure created by de dev team that inserts details into an audit table. It creates a table variable after inserting values into that then it inserts into the real table. The application spawns a lot of concurrent connections so the creation and destruction of these table variables takes place with hunderts of concurrent connections. The process becomes painstakingly slow and the main wait is the resource_semaphore. The problem is that although the engine has a maximum of 30 GB and a minimum of 20 GB memory it never uses more than 4 GB ... basically leaves the memory unused but chokes on resource_semaphore wait. Even the declaration of the table variable takes a lot (if I select only the declare X as table variable it takes a few seconds to execute). It is true that the sproc uses a function that does some string manipulation.  My employer says that The exact same code and shema runs without problems on oracle on exact same hardware and expects me to make sql server perform the same. I could not find a script to at least force the sql engine to take up the minimum memory and don't fall under it again. Bellow is the sproc and the function

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateAuditTrailDetailBulk]
(
    @auditTrailId INT,
    @tableNameArray NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @fieldNameArray NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @oldValueArray NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @newValueArray NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @oldValueTextArray NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @newValueTextArray NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @AuditTrailDetail TABLE
    (
      AuditTrailId int  NOT NULL, 
      TableName nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
      FieldName nvarchar(2000) NOT NULL,
      OldValue nvarchar(max) NULL,
      NewValue nvarchar(max) NULL,
      OldValueText nvarchar(max) NULL,
      NewValueText nvarchar(max) NULL
    )

    INSERT INTO @AuditTrailDetail (AuditTrailId, TableName, FieldName, OldValue, NewValue, OldValueText, NewValueText)
    SELECT 
        @auditTrailId AS AuditTrailId,
        tn.item AS TableName,
        fn.item AS FieldName,
        NULLIF(ov.item, 'NULL') AS OldValue,
        NULLIF(nv.item, 'NULL') AS NewValue,
        NULLIF(ovt.item, 'NULL') AS OldValueText,
        NULLIF(nvt.item, 'NULL') AS NewValueText
    FROM 
        (SELECT rn, item FROM dbo.StringSplit_xml_nulltest1(@tableNameArray, '||')) tn
        INNER JOIN (SELECT rn, item FROM dbo.StringSplit(@fieldNameArray, '||')) fn ON fn.rn = tn.rn
        INNER JOIN (SELECT rn, item FROM dbo.StringSplit(@oldValueArray, '||')) ov ON ov.rn = tn.rn
        INNER JOIN (SELECT rn, item FROM dbo.StringSplit(@newValueArray, '||')) nv ON nv.rn = tn.rn
        INNER JOIN (SELECT rn, item FROM dbo.StringSplit(@oldValueTextArray, '||')) ovt ON ovt.rn = tn.rn
        INNER JOIN (SELECT rn, item FROM dbo.StringSplit(@newValueTextArray, '||')) nvt ON nvt.rn = tn.rn

    INSERT INTO dbo.AuditTrailDetail (AuditTrailId, TableName, FieldName, OldValue, NewValue, OldValueText, NewValueText)
    SELECT AuditTrailId, TableName, FieldName, OldValue, NewValue, OldValueText, NewValueText FROM @AuditTrailDetail
END

GO


CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[StringSplit](
    @input VARCHAR(8000) -- List of delimited items
  , @delimiter VARCHAR(8000) = ',' -- delimiter that separates items
)
RETURNS @List TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000))

BEGIN
    DECLARE @item VARCHAR(8000)

    WHILE CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@input,0) <> 0
        BEGIN

            SELECT
                @item=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@input,1,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@input,0)-1))),
                @input=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@input,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@input,0)+LEN(@delimiter),LEN(@input))))

            IF LEN(@item) > 0
                INSERT INTO @List SELECT @item
            END

            IF LEN(@input) > 0
                INSERT INTO @List SELECT @input -- Put the last item in

            RETURN
    END

GO
```

Comment: `[dbo].[StringSplit]` in OP returns no rn , are you sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the wait type in your case may be due to incorrect statistics  caused by below type of queries...

> INNER JOIN (SELECT rn, item FROM dbo.StringSplit(@fieldNameArray, '||')) fn ON fn.rn = tn.rn
>           INNER JOIN (SELECT rn, item FROM dbo.StringSplit(@oldValueArray, '||')) ov ON ov.rn = tn.rn

**[How SQLServer executes a query](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlqueryprocessing/2010/02/16/understanding-sql-server-memory-grant/):**

> Required memory: Minimum memory needed to run sort and hash join. It is called required because a query would not start without this memory available. SQL server uses this memory to create internal data structures to handle sort and hash join.

I believe SQLServer compiled a wrong plan  due to lack of statistics and the choosed a  join type which  requires huge required memory grant

To resolve this..try changing the query to..

```
Insert into #sometemp
SELECT rn, item FROM dbo.StringSplit(@fieldNameArray, '||')
```

When you insert into temp table like above and do the join after ,SQL will able to guess statistics and hence choose an appropriate plan which doesn't involve huge memory grant